# Openpyxl - cell manipulation

Tags: python, openpyxl

Per this tutorial: http://zetcode.com/python/openpyxl/ view code below: For the code : **print("{0:8} {1:8}".format(c1.value, c2.value))** why is it 0:8/1:8 and not 6 , considering it is only printing out 6 keys/ values???

import openpyxl

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('items.xlsx')

sheet = book.active

cells = sheet['A1': 'B6']

for c1, c2 in cells:
**print("{0:8} {1:8}".format(c1.value, c2.value))**
```

which returns:
Items    Quantity
coins    23
chairs   3
pencils  5
bottles  8
books    30

Answer (score 1):

The :8 from `{0:8}{1:8}` is used for Padding, it has only impact on the way the data is displayed. It has nothing to do with the number of keys/values in the cells.

Check here for more info about the Padding: [Padding Variable Substitution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3#padding-variable-substitutions)